# preg replace to add # if missing when posting form

Tags: php, preg-replace

So I'm somewhat familiar with preg_replace and I'm using it throughout my site to do a number of things. However, I can't seem to identify a solution to achieve this one goal, as I'm trying to perform this check at the time of posting the data.

I have a form that has a text field for only the purpose of a hashtag and text to be entered (#example). I basically just need to check to see if the user entered a hashtag for the first character and if not, then add it when the form is posted. If the user entered a hashtag then nothing needs to be changed. This is my code that I'm using right now and it works as desired, but I need to ensure a hashtag is being entered first.

```
$data = preg_replace('#[^\#a-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST['data']);
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample valid/invalid inputs? I think I understand, but I would like to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

You described exactly what you need to do! Just check if the first character is a pound symbol, if not, add it. You wouldn't use `preg_replace` in this case.

```
$data = ...;
$data = ($data{0} == "#" ? "":"#") . $data;
```

Comment: Sweet! That's exactly what I was missing! Thanks for the fast reply...that worked beautifully!

Comment: I just noticed something and I failed to mention it before. This is not a required field, so if nothing is entered then it still inserts a # when the form is posted? Is there another check that can be added to eliminate this from occurring as well?